# PHP: How to index bound variables?

Tags: variables, indexing, bind

Also, how do you index bound values? For example, suppose I have:

```
oci_parse($handler, "SELECT * FROM table where something = :bv_name['index']")

oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":bv_name", $varname);
```

That indexing obviously doesn't work. Is there anyway to cleanly do this in PHP?

Comment: No one knows how to bind multiple variables? Or index? Free points here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the specific index:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid ":bv_name", $varname['index']);
```

and then use just `:bv_name` in the query.

Comment: I see, never thought about that, thanks! Is there a way to bind multiple variables at once though?